# Light database server options for a small business application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Hi there and many thanks in advance, Im veeery newby.

I am building a small visual basic 2010 application and I need a better choice for my database (around 20 tables), since now Im using SQL server express 2008 and as far as I understand it is too big and complicated for me (just installing it was a pain for me)

I am looking for an application that will be easy to distribute (maybe just an installer and thats it!) and that can run without problems on old computers with windows xp.
The last thing is that I want to have to chance to install just a client version of my app on a computer and tell it to connect to the database wich will be running on other computer on the same LAN (or maybe on a web server on the future!).

In other words I would like to have the option of selecting "where" is the database to read/write on.

I will thank advices for this implemtation and will respond if somebody needs more details before answering.

Comment: If you are looking for an embedded database, you might want look into Firebird.

Comment: Would [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) be feasible?

Comment: What have you looked at, and how do they match your requirements?

Comment: I have not tried anything else sql server express... expect reading a bit from here and there about SQLlite, mysql, sql server compact, sql server localdb, postgreSQL... but it all made me really hard to make a choice. I know I need something free and light, but with server capabilities. Wich ones of them got it all?

Comment: If you;ve already written your app to use SQL Server Express, and you don't want to rewrite it, and you want a database that's easy to deploy, I suggest SQL Server Express LocalDB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MySql is open source and quite easy to use, especially with a tool like PHP MyAdmin:

http://www.mysql.com/

Comment: If the application is commercial, then MySQL is **not** free to distribute (because of the GPL)

Comment: Didn´t know about that issue on Gpl licences. So... it reduces the options more and more isn´t it?

Answer (score 0):

Well installing sqlserver in not rocketscience al you  need to execute  .exe . 
Though if you looking for opensource database then  have a look at **mongodb**

Comment: yeah I know, but the time I lost until got the sqlexpress service up and running on a windows xp sp3 machine the other day was no joke at all.
Im gonna check that. Thanks!